# "View on Instagram" button in an embedded Instagram video only opens in parent window

Tags: iframe, embed, instagram, target

Here is the standard iframe code they give for embedding.

Is there anything I can add to this that will change the target for the "View on Instagram" button that appears when you mouse over the word Instagram in the iframe? I'd prefer it opened a new tab or new window.

Here is the article where I currently have it embedded.

http://www.pdga.com/when-it-rains-it-pours

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with embedding instagram media before, but this seems to be a common gripe (understandably). See [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-instagram-embed/faq/) FAQ post on a wordpress plugin which I assume is similar to what you're using

Answer (score 0):

That link is within the Instagram embed iframe, you cannot change it, if you don't want people to click and go out of your page, you can hide the top section of iframe like this: http://blog.initlabs.com/post/59132920494/how-to-position-a-section-of-iframe-in-a-div